# Xbox Live Unity Plugin

Tags: xbox-live

So I just got accepted into the Xbox Live Creators Program, which is awesome. 
Anyways, I can't seem to find the Xbox Live Unity Plugin anywhere.

I'm trying to download it from this link:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/games/xbox/docs/xboxlive/get-started/creators/configure-xbox-live-in-unity

But link seems to be broken. Any help on that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like those docs have an error.  You can get the plug-in here: https://github.com/Microsoft/xbox-live-unity-plugin/releases

Please let us know if you have any further questions.